# Can you loop through every column in a data frame to find the count of NA values in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, null

I am working with a data frame that consists of 322,055 rows and 51 columns. It is for a homework assignment and the question I am stuck on is "remove any columns with more than 50% nulls". I have figured out how to find the percentage of nulls for particular columns by running the following code (referring to the data set as df):

`total_cases<-nrow(df)`

`print(sum(is.na(df$col1)/total_cases)*100)`

How could I get this to loop through every column in the data set? I can't use this code for all 51 columns.

Comment: You can do `df[, colMeans(is.na(df)) < 0.5]`

Answer (score 4):

An easier option is to get the proportion of `NA`s on each column with `colMeans`, then use that to create a logical vector and subset the columns

```
dfnew <- df[, colMeans(is.na(df)) < 0.5]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I ran this code and it returned a table with 49 columns, is there a way to know which columns it removed other than comparing it to the original df and trying to figure it out myself? Also, I am supposed to write code to get the percentage but am allowed to hardcode the list of columns to remove.

Comment: @LeighAnneRobinson If you want to know the names `i1 <- colMeans(is.na(df)) < 0.5; nm1 <- names(df)[!i1]`.  This solution is one way to remove the columns.  as for the specific part of a loop, it may be better if you work on loop code by yourself and solve.  That way, you don't forget and learn.

Comment: @AndyRominger Please post that as your own solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Another base R solution:

```
clean_df <- df[,sapply(df, function(x){sum(is.na(x))/length(x) < .5})]
```

Determine which vectors were dropped:

```
setdiff(names(df), names(clean_df))
```